How to remove this Android Studio warning?
This might seem like a duplicate, but it is not.
I am aware that this issue has been posted many times on different platforms (example 1; example 2; example 3, but this is a different case that I believe deserves its own thread.
Every new Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project I create is immediately flagged with this warning:
Duplicate content roots detected
Path [/Users/username/Downloads/KotlinProject/composeApp/src/commonMain/resources] of module [KotlinProject.composeApp.commonMain] was removed from modules [KotlinProject.composeApp.main]
They are all dealing with a Test package and that's basically where their problem lies, as for me I am using Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile and Test packages are not the problem here. I suspect the duplication to be due to the shared code between the Android and iOS platform. I'm pretty sure of that but not totally. Here is a brand new KMM project created from the KMP Wizard. I didn't change anything, this way anyone could try to reproduce the same warning on their own machine if they want.
As for anyone wondering, I am using the latest version of macOS on an M1 chip. I am pretty sure this is irrelevant but we never know. The Android Studio version is also the latest.
Also, I tried all the solutions mentioned in the examples above and none of them works for me.
P.S: Is this warning even that much of a problem? Is it gonna cause me trouble in the long run?

It's a warning that you can safely ignore. The Compose team needs help from the Android Gradle Plugin team to fix, so until that happens we all just have to live with it ¯_(ツ)_/¯.
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/2913#issuecomment-1482432764
